# Assignment of module objects while importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to import an empty list from a module and trying to assign a different value to it . But apparently Python is not supporting module item assignment . What could be a different way to tackle this?

In a.py

```
b=[]
```

In 2.py

```
import a
list1=b
list1[0]=1
list1[1]=2
list1[2]=3
```

So when we are doing this, we are getting a "module object does not support item assignment" error.
How can we tackle this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `a` is the module, the list is `a.a`.

Comment: As we want to access a variable in a module in another module without running the whole operational module.

Comment: Your import did not import the list `a` but the module `a`. Hence the error. Please name your list different from your module and try again.

Comment: Perhaps `list1 = a.a`. in any case it is ugly

Comment: Also naming a module by the same name is a sign of bad design (and datetime is no exception)

Comment: Okay I have changed the names, as we can see above . I still am getting the same error.

Comment: The code you give can't produce that error, it would give a `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`. So `b` is not what you tell us it is.

Answer (score 0):

When your code does this

```
import a
list1=b
```

you seem to be expecting that `b` is the same as the `b` you defined in module `a`. But it isn't. To do what you expect, your code should either do

```
list1=a.b
```

or it should do

```
from a import b
list1=b
```

Without one of these approaches Python regards `b` in `2.py` as an entirely separate variable from the `b` in `a.py`.

It looks like you are expecting

```
import a
```

to make all the names in `a.py` part of the `2.py` namespace. And imports in some other languages work like that (for example Turbo Pascal `use`). You can do that in Python like this

```
from a import *
```

but that is regarded as poor Python style because in the general case you really have no idea what your `import` statement is importing.